# Using a for loop to get and update attributes from an XML web page

Tags: xml, winforms, for-loop

I am trying to display data from a web page in XML in two boxes I've created on a form.

I want an attribute, "b", to be displayed in a box called "bText", and a different attribute, "a", to be displayed in a box called "aText".  I also have a box on the form called "inputText", which is where I tell the program what the attributes correspond to.

The code below works fine, but I want to put a loop in to get it to update constantly without having to press return all the time (hence the attempted for loop in the comment).  When I try to put the infinite for loop in, the form only displays "a".  It also takes ages to display it and doesn't update at all.  How can I get the loop to show both "a" and "b" and update them properly?

The code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Timers;

namespace QuoteForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CheckEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)

                //for (; ; )
                {
                    string value = inputText.Text;
                    String xmlURL = "*Web page in XML*" + (value);
                    XmlTextReader XmlReader = new XmlTextReader(xmlURL);

                    while (XmlReader.Read())
                    {
                        string b = (XmlReader.GetAttribute("b"));
                        bool result = (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(b));
                        if (result == false)
                        {
                            bText.Text = b;
                        }

                        string a = (XmlReader.GetAttribute("a"));
                        bool result2 = (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a));
                        if (result2 == false)
                        {
                            aText.Text = a;
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A loop like that dominates the UI thread and does not allow controls to update their displays.

Look at the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to do the reading on a separate thread, and then Invoke the update for the UI controls.

Comment: Thanks - I now understand the concept of running complex tasks on a different thread to the UI thread, but I still can't manage to implement BackgroundWorker to make this program work properly.  Would you mind showing me how I could do that?  I'm pretty much an absolute beginner with C# so I'd be extremely grateful for any further help!